# What is the iToffoli gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, universal-gates

What is the itoffoli gate and what is its importance in quantum computing?
How it can be implemented it in qiskit?

Answer (score 1):

According to "[High-fidelity iToffoli gate for fixed-frequency superconducting qubits](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2108.10288)" by Kim et la.

> Similar to the Toffoli gate, the iToffoli gate inverts a target qubit conditioned upon two control qubits but with a phase shift of $\pi/2$. This three-qubit gate can also be used for arbitrary Boolean operations and forms a universal quantum gate set with the Hadamard gate.

Fig. 1 in this paper contains a circuit diagram to realize it. From this diagram you should be able to implement this gate in Qiskit.

[image]